# Flutter ObjectBox - Can't generate DB model with custom class

Tags: java, flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Following the [NoSQL Database Storage | Flutter ObjectBox (vs Sqlite, Sqflite, Hive)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBlr8F8m9lo), I am trying to setup an ObjectBox database with multiple classes. I currently have the following classes,

**Exercise.dart**

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
@Sync()
class Exercise {
  int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? target;
  final String? bodyPart;
  final String? equipment;
  final String? gifUrl;

   Exercise({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.name,
    required this.target,
    required this.bodyPart,
    required this.equipment,
    required this.gifUrl,
  });

  factory Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Exercise(
        id: int.tryParse(json['id'].toString()),
        name: json["name"].toString(),
        target: json["target"].toString(),
        bodyPart: json["bodyPart"].toString(),
        equipment: json["equipment"].toString(),
        gifUrl: json["gifUrl"].toString());
  }
}
```

and
**Set.dart**

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';
import 'package:pump_that_iron/models/exercise.dart';

@Entity()
@Sync()
class Set {
  int? id;
  final Exercise? exercise;
  final int? repetitions;

  Set({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.exercise,
    required this.repetitions,
  });
}
```

From these classes I am trying to build a model class using ObjectBox and the `flutter pub run build_runner build` command. However, whenever that command is run, I get the following error,

> Cannot use the default constructor of 'Set': don't know how to initialize param exercise - no such property.

as well as

> [WARNING] objectbox_generator:resolver on lib/models/set.dart: skipping property 'exercise' in entity 'Set', as it has an unsupported type: 'Exercise?'

Initially, when running the build command with the `Exercise.dart` being the only present class, it is successful. However, as soon as I add the `Set.dart` file **containing the Exercise class as a variable**, I am no longer able to build. Another thing to note, is that when the Exercice variable is omitted from the Set class, it runs successfully.

I found the following [How initialize Objectbox entity with custom type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838139/how-initialize-objectbox-entity-with-custom-type) SO thread with a similar problem and tried to replicate the steps by,

1. Adding a getExercise getter in the `Set.dart` class and adding it to the constructor

```
Set({
    this.id = 0,
    this.exercise = getExercise,
    required this.repetitions,
  });

  get getExercise => Exercise(
      name: "name",
      target: "target",
      bodyPart: "bodyPart",
      equipment: "equipment",
      gifUrl: "gifUrl");
```

2. This required me to make the `Exercise.dart` constructor constant, and making the following changes

```
class Exercise {
  @Id(assignable: true)
  final int? id;
  ...

  const Exercise({
    this.id = 0,
    ...
  });
```

This is now giving me a `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.` error when trying to set the exercise variable at `this.exercise = getExercise`. I tried following the instructions from another SO thread [Default values of an optional parameter must be constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907159/default-values-of-an-optional-parameter-must-be-constant), but I am still having issues.

I was wondering if anybody could help me set up my database and explain what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectBox just supports storing [some base types by default](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types). For custom types you have to either [map them to a supported type](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types#convert-annotation-and-property-converter), or I assume what you are looking for in this case [create a relation](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations) to an `@Entity` class:

```
@Entity()
class Set {
  int? id;
  final exercise = ToOne<Exercise>();
  final int? repetitions;
}

// To change the ToOne target:
set.exercise.target = Exercise();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend! My problem is solved :)